# After HTAccess RewriteRule stop direct call to folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using a Rewriterule to create more suitable URLs has created a problem of multiple URLS for the same content.
I've rewritten the folder /tours/halfday/ to /halfday.html. The issue is that /tours/halfday/ is still addressable in the browser by the user. How can I stop the address being accessible?

If I redirect /tours/halfday/ I get internal server error.

```
RewriteRule ^halfday\.html$ /tours/halfday/ [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rearrange your command like so:

```
RewriteRule ^tours/halfway/$ /halfway.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but on my IONOS webserver that format throws a 404 error.